# Convert data retrieved from spring-boot to JSON and fetch it in angular front-end

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, angular6, postgresql-9.4

I want to retrieve all the skills form the skills entity in postgresql and send it using get method to the Angular front end.In HTTP request I need to send a JSON object.How can I convert the retrieved values from the postgresql to a JSON object?

I have connected the postgresql db using spring JPA. And also I get a string values to my front end. But I wanted those as JSON object

This is my controller class

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class SkillsController {
    @Autowired
    SkillsRepository skillsRepository;



    @RequestMapping("/getSkills")
    @GetMapping("/getSkills")
    @CrossOrigin
    public String getSkills(){
        String result = "";

        for (Skills skill : skillsRepository.findAll()){
            result +=  skill.toString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This is my Angular front end ts file

```
public getAllSkills() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/getSkills';
    this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(
      res => {
        alert(res);
      },
      err => {
        alert('Error in retrieving');
      }
    );
  }
```

I want to convert my retrieved valus in to JSON object and catch that object using get method in the front end

Comment: @Coder, has given the proper solution. In client side don't forget to change the `responseType: 'json'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses `Jackson` serialization/deserialization by default and also the return type is `Json`. Instead of returning a String return type, return the object itself and it will be converted into Json without any additional code from your end. You controller would typically look as specified below.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class SkillsController {

    @Autowired
    SkillsRepository skillsRepository;

    @GetMapping("/getSkills")
    public List<Skill> getSkills() {
        return skillsRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

I will be doing some rewrite to your post. so the answer is pretty straight forward, you can simply return list from the repository and Spring will convert the list to the appriopriate JSON object or array.

```
@CrossOrigin
public class SkillsController {

 public SkillsRepository skillsRepository;

 public SkillsController(SkillsRepository _skillsRepository){
       skillsRepository = _skillsRepository;
  }

  @RequestMapping("/getSkills")
  @CrossOrigin
  public List<skillEntity> getSkills(){ 
     return (List<skillEntity>)skillsRepository.findAll();
  }

}
```